# Youtube API Player, disable related videos

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

At the end of playback, a suggested video (only 1 video) permanently appears.

This recommended video appears even though `rel = 0`, that is, the URI contains `VIDEO_ID?rel=0`. How can I deactivate the recommended video?

Here is my code:

```js
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('stage-video', {
        videoId: 'q2eyNf3n_AU?rel=0',
        playerVars: { 
            'html5': 1,
            'rel': '0',
            'playsinline': 1,
            'autoplay': 0,
            'controls': 0, 
            'enablejsapi': 1,
            'showinfo': 0,
            'suggestedQuality': 'hd720',
            'wmode': 'transparent'
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue might be that you're sending a string instead of an integer. Try sending the variable as an integer instead of a string like so:

```js
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('stage-video', {
        videoId: 'q2eyNf3n_AU',
        playerVars: { 
            'html5': 1,
            'rel': 0,
            'playsinline': 1,
            'autoplay': 0,
            'controls': 0, 
            'enablejsapi': 1,
            'showinfo': 0,
            'suggestedQuality': 'hd720',
            'wmode': 'transparent'
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
```

I also wouldn't suspect the URL encoded parameter to work from the `videoId` parameter inside the `YT.Player` API, so try removing it from there as well.

Comment: Thank you Ben, the recommendation is still comming.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using hardcoded url on the iframe. If you are using url you can add `&rel=0` in the video url.

Also remove change `'0'` into `0`, remove '.

Answer (score 0):

This parameter "rel" affects only the proposals at the end of the video. But I need something that disables the annotations (left small banner below ) with the class "iv-promo-video".